# Analysing SQL statement in trigger triggered by this statement

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update

Im trying to create few triggers, that will rise an exception if someone tries to update a row but not setting a specific column value
lets say that i have a table

```
CREATE TABLE entry (
   id integer NOT NULL,
   value varchar NOT NULL,
   modificationAuthor varchar NOT NULL
);
```

i wont make sure, that if someone tries to update value, he will pass a value of `modificationAuthor` column in that UPDATE, even if new value is the same as previous.

`UPDATE entry SET value="aaa", modificationAuthor='Anonymus' WHERE id=1;` <- Correct

`UPDATE entry SET value="aaa" WHERE id=1;` <- Incorrect, should rise an esception.

I know how to create a trigger and rise an exception, but how to tell if current query has that `modificationAuthor='SOMETHING'`?

EDIT:
I need to also allow situations like

`UPDATE entry SET value="aaa", modificationAuthor='Anonymus' WHERE id=1;`
updating a row of table where `modificationAuthor` has already value `Anonymus`.

Might seems to be pointless to care about it above condition is also true, but im trying to avoid allowing updates without pointing an author (in with case last author will be taken as author of newest edit)

Comment: I think the only option you have, is to create a procedure (function) that does the update and expects three mandatory parameters.

Comment: i hope you're mistaken :P i'm trying to do a mechanism that will be transparent to user of database
I have an idea of walk around but it's quite messy and weird. If no one will post a solution, then i'll have to try implement it.

Comment: Unfortunately, @a_horse is right. You have to write a function to update your table or check it in your application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL 8.2: Require specific column to be present in UPDATE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538698/postgresql-8-2-require-specific-column-to-be-present-in-update-statement)

Comment: it is the same problem, unfortunately it doesn't contain an answer i'm hoping for :(

Answer (score 1):

In a trigger function you have two special record variables `old` and `new` containing values before and after update respectively.

```
create or replace function my_trigger() 
returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    if new.modificationAuthor = old.modificationAuthor then
        raise exception 'You have to change modificationAuthor';
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger my_trigger before update on entry
    for each row execute procedure my_trigger();
```

Of course, you can add your logic to the function code or change it, e.g.
- `if new.modificationAuthor != 'Anonymous' then`
- `if new.modificationAuthor = '' then`, etc.

See [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/trigger-definition.html) for details.

In a trigger function you cannot find out if a value in `new` record was delivered by update query.

Comment: Consider situation, when last modification was done by `XXX` user, and few moments later, the same user modifies it again. he will `SET` value properly, but exception will be raised due to equal value.